# What are years based on in the saga "A Song of Ice and Fire?"

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In these books there is quite a lot of focus on realism - there are weight units and length units based on things corresponding to the society's technological stage, and many things are based on internal events in that world. However, since there is so much focus on these details, I wonder what are years based on? In the real world we have developed them because of the cyclic changes of weather, but in this world these changes are irregular, and summers and winters are both stated to last years. So, what is a "year" based on in that world?